# given a list with integers separated by math symbols, find if a certain value can be calculated by placing braces

Tags: python, recursion, lis

I'm trying to write a function which get:

1. An integer. (s)
2. A list with integers separated by math symbols.(L)

By using recursion to determinate if the value of s can be calculate from the list by placing braces.
Any ideas for a solution? I thought about using `eval()` function.

for example:
L = [6,'-',4,'*',2,'+',3]
s=10
Return: True, since: `(6-4)*(2+3)=10`

L = [6,'-',4,'*',2,'+',3]
s=1
Return: True, since: `(6-(4*2))+3=1`

L = [6,'-',4,'*',2,'+',3]
s=100
Return: False, since there is no valid way to place braces in L which will lead to a solution of 100.

Thanks :)

Comment: i don't see the difference between the first example and the second one, what are the rules?  [6,'-',4,'*',2,'+',3] = 6 -4*2+3 = 6 - (4*2) +3 or  6 - (4 * (2 + 3))

Comment: The rules are: if a given integer ( lets call it s) can be calculated from the list (L) by placing braces somewhere in the list- the function return True. 
Else the function return False.
In the first example: a valid way to calculate 10 from L by placing braces- return True.
In the second example: a valid way to calculate 1 from L by placing braces- return True

Answer (score 0):

Let's describe the recursion in words, I think it is better to understand, we just need to define exactly what it does, it is really like induction.

rec function: get an input a list of numbers and return all the combinations of braces(examples later).

base: list with one element, for example [3], the function return (3) which is the only combination. or list with 3 element which simply returns (2+3)

assumption: we can solve it for a list of size N -2, for your example:[6,'-',4,'*',2,'+',3] N = 7, so we can solve it for list with size 5 [4,'*',2,'+',3] and we will get all the combinations:

1. (4*2) + (3)
2. (4) * (2+3)

Step: solve it for N!
what we need to do is to go over all the combination we got from the rec call(if we are on N = 7, its simply 1 and 2 from the example)
and we only need to do the following things for each combination:
put the current number next to the most left number and operate on it, or put it before the braces and put braces on all the expressions, for our example:

from option 1 we get 2 new options

6 -( (4*2) +(3) )

(6 - 4*2) +(3)

from option 2 we get 2 new options

(6-4) * (2+3)

6 - ( (4) * (2+3))

now the rec function returned all the combinations, we can call eval on each of them to check the result

Comment: Thank you, your answer makes it a lot easier to understand. though there is 5th case which is not covered by your method:
(6-4)*2+3=7

Comment: then we missed it in the assumption example, we should have another one 
(4)*(2)+(3), and in each step we simply create this simple expression (6)-(4)*(2)+(3)  (just copy the list) but you get the idea, its all about defining well what happen, and don't miss cases as i did

Answer (score 0):

Full app below.
Works with any formula length.
Parenthesis give order of operators, so we test all combinations.
Testing all permutations of n operators is  n!
with 3 operators as in sample it's 6 tests.
for 8 operators, it will be 40320 ...
The code doesn't stop when the searched value is found as it could be several manner to obtain the same result.

All possible results are shown at the end.
For the given formula : ---- all possible results : {1, 7, 10, -14, -5}

Enjoy

```py
from itertools import permutations

formula = [6,'-',4,'*',2,'+',3] ;
searchedValue = 10 ;

# operators are on odd positions . 
operatorsPositions = list(range(1,len(formula),2)) # [1, 3, 5]
# prepare all permutations eq all parenthesis order . return an array of tuple
permut = list(permutations(operatorsPositions))
print("**** {0} permutations to be tested ****".format(len(permut)))
print(permut)


# around an operator , two operands . return result
def calcAround(aFormula,position):
 op1 = aFormula[position -1]
 op2 = aFormula[position +1]
 operator = aFormula[position]
 # optional trace operation
 # print("calculate ({0:2d} {1} {2:2d})".format(op1,operator,op2));
 if (operator == "-"): return op1-op2;
 if (operator == "+"): return op1+op2;
 if (operator == "*"): return op1*op2;
 if (operator == "/"): return op1/op2;
 #--------------------

# 'op1', 'operator', 'op2'  replaced by result in formula
def reduceAtPosition(someformula,position):
    result = calcAround(someformula,position);
    formulaNew =[];
    for i in range (0,position-1): formulaNew.append(someformula[i]);
    formulaNew.append(result);
    for i in range (position+2,len(someformula)):formulaNew.append(someformula[i]);
    return formulaNew;

# ------- main part --------
#  set to store unique possible results 
allResults = set(())
# try each permutation of operators order 
for aTest in permut: 
  aPermut = list(aTest) # better to have an array in place of tuple
  print('----------------')
  # make a new copy each tour 
  lTempo = formula.copy()
  print("operators sequence: {0}".format(aPermut))

  while(len(aPermut)>0):
    print(lTempo)
    anOpIndice = aPermut[0]
    lTempo = reduceAtPosition(lTempo,anOpIndice);
    # remove first done 
    aPermut = aPermut[1:]  
    for i in range(0,len(aPermut)):
      if (aPermut[i]>anOpIndice): aPermut[i] -= 2
  # 
  final = lTempo[0]
  print("result: {0}".format(final))
  # to respond to question 
  if(final == searchedValue): 
    print('*** found {0} with order or operators positions: {1} '.format(final,aTest))
  
  allResults.add(final)
print('---- all possible results : {0}'.format(allResults))
```

Console results:

```
**** 6 permutations to be tested ****
[(1, 3, 5), (1, 5, 3), (3, 1, 5), (3, 5, 1), (5, 1, 3), (5, 3, 1)]
----------------
operators sequence: [1, 3, 5]
[6, '-', 4, '*', 2, '+', 3]
[2, '*', 2, '+', 3]
[4, '+', 3]
result: 7
----------------
operators sequence: [1, 5, 3]
[6, '-', 4, '*', 2, '+', 3]
[2, '*', 2, '+', 3]
[2, '*', 5]
result: 10
*** found 10 with order or operators positions: (1, 5, 3) 
----------------
operators sequence: [3, 1, 5]
[6, '-', 4, '*', 2, '+', 3]
[6, '-', 8, '+', 3]
[-2, '+', 3]
result: 1
----------------
operators sequence: [3, 5, 1]
[6, '-', 4, '*', 2, '+', 3]
[6, '-', 8, '+', 3]
[6, '-', 11]
result: -5
----------------
operators sequence: [5, 1, 3]
[6, '-', 4, '*', 2, '+', 3]
[6, '-', 4, '*', 5]
[2, '*', 5]
result: 10
*** found 10 with order or operators positions: (5, 1, 3) 
----------------
operators sequence: [5, 3, 1]
[6, '-', 4, '*', 2, '+', 3]
[6, '-', 4, '*', 5]
[6, '-', 20]
result: -14
---- all possible results : {1, 7, 10, -14, -5}
```